# Azure Mobile Service - Access to App_Data is denied

Tags: c#, .net, azure, mobile, service

I have a project type Azure Mobile Service, I try use Membership.ValidateUser. In the local server is working fine.

{"ClassName":"System.UnauthorizedAccessException","Message":"Access to the path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\MobileServicesDotNet\1.0.478\App_Data' is denied.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)\r\n   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)\r\n   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.EnsureDBFile(String connectionString)\r\n   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation)\r\n   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate)\r\n   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password)\r\n   at jLanBriefcaseServices.Controllers.AuthController.Signin(UserLogin userLogin)","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nWinIOError\nmscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.IO.__Error\nVoid WinIOError(Int32, System.String)","HResult":-2147024891,"Source":"mscorlib","WatsonBuckets":null}

Comment: You could use a web based diagnostics tool for Azure called Kudu and follow this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) to check the directory mentioned in the detailed errors. From the errors, I assume there be something wrong with your connection string, do you use a local DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you are referencing a local SQL instance in your Azure mobile app. As I know there is no SQL install in Azure mobile App. You can't use an .mdf file in App_Data. This is why your application could run on local and not working in Azure mobile app. If you want to authorize Azure mobile app, I would suggest you use Azure AD instead, refer to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users/) for more information.